# Append results of DataFrame apply lamda to DateFrame or new Series

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, series

I am using the apply method with a lamda to compute on each row of a Dataframe to return a Series.

`statsSeries =  matchData.apply(lambda row: mytest(row), axis=1)`

where mytest(row) is a function that returns timestamp, float, float.

```
def mytest(row):
    timestamp = row['timestamp'] 
    wicketsPerOver = row['wickets']/row['overs']
    runsPerWicket = row['runs']/row['wickets'] 
    return timestamp, wicketsPerOver, runsPerWicket
```

As I have written it, the statsSeries contains two columns, one an index and the other a tuple of the (timestamp, wicketsPerOver, runsPerWicket).

How can I return a Series with three columns [timestamp,  wicketsPerOver, runsPerWicket]?

Comment: My guess is that you're probably looking to return `row.name, timestamp, wicketsPerOver, runsPerWicket`. That will let you cross-reference the frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to use `pd.Series.apply(pd.Series)`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3, 4]})

def add_some(row):
    return row[0]+1, row[0]+2, row[0]+3

df[[1, 2, 3]] = df.apply(add_some, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.